# Confuse with UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new beginner in iOS programming, I have a UICollectionView method which looks like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

        Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell mainImage].image =[UIImage imageNamed:[cellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        // WHATS HAPPEN AFTER TAP THE VIEW

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [cell mainImage].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [[cell mainImage] addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    //    cell.backgroundColor =[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images-4.png]];

        return cell;
}
```

Now I want to add an if in this method; if user tap the last image in my array then it calls a new method "addtapdetected" and add a new cell in my collection view, now I'm confuse and don't know where I should to set my if and how??
I know that I should to create a new cell but don't know where use that...

Comment: instead of adding a tap gesture, you can just do - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectCellAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. I thik that's the name, and then check id object; if(object == [array lastObject]] { [self addtapdetected];} ... hope that works! and Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
[cell mainImage].image =[UIImage imageNamed:[cellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

to

```
[cell mainImage].image =[UIImage imageNamed:[cellImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
```

In collectionview item is used in place of row.

Second if you want to add a new cell on tap of a cell then you should place the code for that inside this method

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you don't need to use any tap gesture in this method. It automatically detects the cell user tap on.